# How to run docker image in Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

How can I run a docker image in a kubernetes pod?

A teammate of mine has defined a new docker image and pushed it to my team's private registry. I own some code running in our kubernetes cluster and we need to get my code to effectively `docker run gcr.io/our-project/teammates-image:latest`.

I've been looking at enabling docker-in-docker on our kubernetes pods but I'm having little luck. I'm currently experimenting with `minikube` and whenever I try to `docker run` I get: `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`.

I've added

`securityContext:
  privileged: true`

To my container spec. I suspect I need more configuration but haven't figured out what.

I'm also trying to evaluate whether I can `kubectl run --image=gcr.io/our-project/teammates-image:lastest` from within the kubernetes pod.

Is there a "correct" way to run docker images from within a kubernetes pod? How can I run image with docker-in-docker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up using for anyone who may stumble upon this in the future.

Install `kubectl` in the main docker image which needs to run the other docker image. I did this by following [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl). Once you have `kubectl` installed, it should automatically be able to interact with the cluster it's running in and doesn't need extra authentication.

Next, to run the `teammtes-image:latest` docker image you can do something like the following in python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["kubectl", "run", "teammates-image", "--image", "gcr.io/our-project/teammates-image:lastest", "--attach", "--restart", "Never", "--rm"])
```

This should:

1. create a pod
2. run the image
3. return the return code of the container
4. delete the pod after completion

Comment: Perfect answer. Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run to manipulate the request however you want.